# How to combine two different array with different keys into one single array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays array1 and array 2.Array1 have values with a key name "discount_price" and array2 have values with key name "regular_price".
eg:
[discount_price_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4WQS.png),
[regular_price_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkleV.png)

When i merge them using array merge i get a single array with combined values. i.e if array1 has 10 elements and array2 has 10 elements it merges into an array with 20 elements. [merged_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZDr7.png).

what i want is instead an array with eg:

```
array{"discount_price":10,"regular_price":2},
array{"discount_price":4,"regular_price":3},
```

How can i achieve this ?

```
  $(values).each(function(key, value) {
  //console.log(value);
  if( value.discount_price !==undefined){
    discount_price_array.push({ discount_price: value.discount_price })
  }
   
    });   
   
$(values).each(function(key, value) {
  //console.log(value);
  if( value.regular_price !==undefined){
    regular_price_array.push({ regular_price: value.regular_price })
  }

    }); 

   var finalarray =$.merge(discount_price_array,regular_price_array 
     )
```

Comment: both arrays have the same length?

Comment: @SaeedShamloo yes

Comment: You can use `map` of pure js or `$.map` instead of merge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` and 'destructuring (...)'

`map`: lets to iterate over an array and return the same length new array, where you decide what will be returned in every iteration.

(...) `spread` , allows you to spread the (outer properties) properties in a new object or array, you are basically assigning all object properties to new object, since you are spreading two object in the same new object, they are being merged.

```js
// if both of them have the same length 

let arr1 = [{'property1': 10 }, {'property1': 10 },];

let arr2 = [{'property2': 20 }, {'property2': 20 },];

let result = arr1.map((object, index)=> ({...object, ...arr2[index] }));
console.log(result);
```

simple `map only`

```js
// if you want to pick which property to assign

let arr1 = [{'property1': 10 }, {'property1': 10 }];

let arr2 = [{'property2': 20 }, {'property2': 20 }];

let result = arr1.map((object, index)=> {
  object['property2'] = arr2[index]['property2'];
  return object; 
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This worked thank you very much

Comment: could you explain your code so it can be helpful

Comment: added explanation.